# Conditions for strongly convex function

Tags: convex-analysis

I have a loss function:
$$L(\beta)=\frac{1}{2}\sum_{i=1}^n (y_i -x_i^\top\beta)^2+\frac{\lambda}{2}\|\beta\|_{2}^2$$

I calculated:
$$\nabla L(\beta) = 
X^T (X \beta - y)+ \lambda \beta$$
$$\nabla^2 L(\beta) = 
X^T X + \lambda I$$

Now I have to find conditions under which loss function is strongly-convex.
How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Solved it.
when $\lambda > 0$
and when X (mxn) full rank and $m \geq n$

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).